# Can a hospital bill me based on my name and date of birth?

Tags: medical-records, procedural-expectations, hospital, medical-billing, medical-ethics

If an out-of-state hospital has none of my information except for name and date of birth, can they bill me?

I was hospitalized in NY for a night for excessive drinking, what can I expect or should I do in the coming days?

Comment: Are you saying that the hospital bill is legitimate?

Comment: Also, are you asking about the practicality of the hospital finding you or are you asking whether you would have a legal defense to avoid paying? E.g., "According to the New York Truth in Medical Billing Act of 2003, a medical bill that does not specify at least three items of personally identifiable information for the patient is presumed fraudulent unless it has been countersigned by the Surgeon General, Governor, or the Chief of Police in the jurisdiction in which the treatment allegedly occurred".

Comment: Are you sure they did not go through your wallet to ID you while you were drunk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to healthcare billing rather than medical sciences.